# Stream dataset from db

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I saw an interview question asking how to process a dataset from db if this dataset is so huge that it doesn't fit memory.
The answer was: using stream.
OK, sounds reasonable.
But what exactly tools should be used in Java to achieve that?
`query.getResultList()` gets the whole list at once, and there is no any streams in Query API.
If not JPA, maybe Hibernate itself has it?
Thank you.

Comment: i'd imagine most JPA implementations have some query hint to allow all results not be pulled in to memory (or not retain references to them so they can be gced). Perhaps you should look at the docs for your chosen implementation and see if it has something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use paging in your queries to select sets at a time. Then once you are done processing that set, go back to the database and get the next set. you could wrap this functionality in a List interface and make it transparent to the user of the list interface

You can also use frameworks that would do this for you such as [ActiveJDBC](http://javalite.io/activejdbc)

In ActiveJDBC lite, you can use the [ModelListener](http://javalite.io/record_selection)

Comment: Yes, I also decided to go paging, but I was told that is not right.

Answer (score 0):

The java sql package and relevant implementations (for oracle, mysql, etc) have Statement and ResultSet classes. The latter will iterate over the fetched records without pulling them all into memory at once. Multiple db hits are a side effect of this method,though they are transparent to the developer .

Comment: Ooh sorry didn't read your question that way. Was wondering why you missed basic jdbc construct :) afaik nothing of that sort in hibernate but I'm a newbie there